# Basic prime summation

Tags: python, primes

I wrote basic Python code for the summation of n primes. It works but I wanted to find out how I could improve it and what shortcuts I missed.

```
    """ So this program is designed to add up the first 'b' primes
    ==> Prime number is defined as a number only divisible by itself or 1"""


def is_prime(a):
    """ This function determines if a number is prime"""

    pri = True
    n = 2
    while n < a:
        if a % n == 0:
            pri = False
        n += 1
    return pri

def addition_of_primes(b):
    """ This function will find the first b primes.
        It stores each one in a list and then we take 
        the sum of that list"""

    primes = []
    candidate = 2
    while len(primes) < b:
        if is_prime(candidate):
            primes.append(candidate)
        candidate += 1
    return sum(primes)

print addition_of_primes(1000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the 'use a different algorithm' approach. (Even though the Sieve of Eratosthenes is better).

There are two very common optimisations you missed in the prime checker.

1. You can increment by 2, so you skip all the even numbers.
2. You can `return False` early to avoid waisted CPU cycles.

There is another less common optimisation.

- Going to the square root of `n`.

There is also a rare algorithm, that goes in steps of 6.
But that's uncommon, and if you need that speed, use the Sieve.

---

As for your `addition_of_primes` function,
I would not build up an intermarry list.

One way to do that is:

```
amount = 1
total = 2
candidate = 3
while amount < b:
    if is_prime(candidate):
        amount += 1
        total += candidate
    candidate += 2

return total
```

Or if you want this all in one line:

```
import itertools
return sum(itertools.islice(itertools.ifilter(is_prime, itertools.count(2)), b))
```

---

If you add the optimisations to `is_prime`, you should get:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num == 2:
        return True

    if num % 2 == 0:
        return False

    for div in xrange(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if num % div == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks allot. And I just read about the Sieve of Eratosthenes which is really neat. Only been coding for two weeks so it's really nice to get feedback on what I code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Sieve of Eratosthenes. The complexity of this algorithm is O(n log log n)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Please review the code, rather than sharing alternative algorithms.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes pointing out that a better algorithm exists, with justification, seems legit to me.